# How to handle api error in react and show custom log

Tags: reactjs

```
componentDidMount() {
  let url = FormatUrl(`/user/`)
  fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
  }).catch(err => {
    if (err){
      console.log('has error')
    }
  })
}
```

Here i am trying to fetch data from a wrong api.
And it is throwing  below error.

```
Home.jsx:20 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I 
Is there any way to hide this error and display a simple message in console without throwing 
exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The promise isn't rejected by the fetch API simply because it fails to reach the endpoint. What you need to do is check the response in your first .then(). You have response.status which returns the status code, or you could use response.ok which returns true if the status code is within the 200-299 interval.
A more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/)